# How to make a TextView scrollable within a RecyclerView that has an ItemTouchHelper for swiping?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, textview, android-widget

Here is a screenshot of my app.

[image]

The circled area is a RecyclerView with a TouchHelper so you can swipe left to delete items in the list.

Each item in the recycler list is a CardView that contains a linear layout and the text is a simple TextView.

I want to be able to scroll the text within each of the TextViews as well as be able to swipe to delete, but only swipe to delete is working.

What do I need to do to enable scrolling of these TextViews, which have more text than can fit in the 4 lines?

Here's some of the relevant code and layout.

```
    // Initialize comment list adapter
    commentAdapter = CommentListAdapter(this)
    binding.comments.adapter = commentAdapter
    binding.comments.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    binding.comments.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))
    val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(SwipeToDeleteCallback(commentAdapter, (ItemTouchHelper.LEFT or ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT)))
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(binding.comments)
```

Here's the XML for each of the "comment" TextViews. Note how I'm setting a vertical scrollbar, as most of the Internet recommends. And I've limited the number of lines to 4 in order to keep each individual item smaller.

My limiting of the number of lines to 4 in the TextView is perhaps not what the system expects, since normally the entirety of the text would be displayed within each RecyclerView item. And indeed it works that way if I remove the maxLines limitation.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/comment_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:maxLines="4"
    android:text="@string/comment_text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `TextView` inside a `ScrollView`

```
<ScrollView 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/comment_text"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:maxLines="4"
android:text="@string/comment_text" />

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I did that based on other stack overflow questions, but it had zero effect. Also my top level layout element is a CardView not a ScrollView. This is for the individual items in the list, not the overall activity page.

Comment: In this example, what's the point of the LinearLayout?